# Parsing a text config file in perl

Tags: perl, parsing, text

Hi guys so I have a config text file that looks like this.

```
$name
search_key,0x0

$name2
search_key2,0x1
```

each block can have multiple entries like below

```
$name
search_key1,0x1
search_key2,0x0
```

There may also be more than one value.

```
$name
search_key, 0x1, 0x0
```

What I am aiming to do is use each $name to rename a file, then the key word will be searched in the file and the value changed e.g search_key1 might have an original value of 0x0 which will be changed to 0x1.

I have finished the second part of what I am aiming to do, be hard coding the values into my script, but I can't for the life of me figure out what way I should parse the file and I have been stuck on it so long all my ideas are stale any one have any advice? I don't even know which direction to take at this stage

Comment: I'm confused - "I can't for the life of me figure out what way I should parse the file" -> parse the config file? or parse the file referenced by `$name` ?

Comment: _> search_key1 might have an original value of 0x0 which will be changed to 0x1_ - does this mean you need to both read and update the config file?

Comment: Ok sorry clearly i didn't explain this very well. Carl I was talking about the config file, Snoopy the config file will not be updated I am using the config file to change binary values in another file which is renamed $name

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using yaml for your config file instead of writing your own parser config file and parser.

Here's what a yaml file of data like yours might look like.

```
---
- file
- key:
    search_key:
      search: 0x1
  name: Name
- file
- key:
    search_key1:
      search: 0x1
    search_key2:
      search: 0x0
  name: Name2
- file
- key:
    search_key3:
      replace: 0x0
      search: 0x1
  name: Name3
```

Here's what the data might look like:

```
my $data = [
    file => {
        name => 'Name',
        key  =>  { 'search_key' => { search => '0x1' } }
    },

    file => {
        name => 'Name2',
        key => {
            search_key1 => { search => '0x1' },
            search_key2 => { search => '0x0' }
        }
    },

    file => {
        name => 'Name3',
        key => {
            search_key3 => { search => '0x1', replace => '0x0' }
        }
    }
];
```

so `$data->[2]->{file}->{name}`  would be `Name3`. `$data->[2]->{file}->{key}->{search_key3}->{search}` would be `0x1` and the associated `->{replace}` would be `0x0`.

If you set your data up this way, you can use a for loop to traverse the elements of the $data arrayref.